# VS2015 using the Nightlies

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

I have VS2015RC. I was looking to plug it into the nightly nuget feed.
If i configure the normal way i don't get the intellisense from the nightly feed in project.json

i.e
Nuget Package manager Settings
[image: Nuget Package manager Settings]

Also in the "Nuget Package Manager for Solution" if I change the package source to nightlies, nothing is listed, and it doesn't seem possible to check the "include prerelease" checkbox.

Are there any docs to show how to use the Nightlies with ASP.Net5 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feed link you are setting is incorrect. The correct one is: `https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2`